# How to access a private typedef as a parameter in a public function

Tags: c++, linked-list

Title says it all.

```
typedef string ListElemType;
class inord_list {
public:
    void insertafter(const ListElemType&, link);
    void insertbefore(const ListElemType&, link);
private:
    struct Node;
    typedef Node* link;
    struct Node
    {
        ListElemType elem;
        link next;
    };
    link head;
    link tail;
    link current;
    link next;
```

Whenever I try to use the "link" as a parameter in the above functions it's an error.
Another question in the same scope as well, if I declared the 2 public functions as private, I can't call one in another. Why so ? even if:

```
this->insertafter(const ListElemType& elem, link p);
```

It gives me syntax error.

Comment: `this->insertafter(const ListElemType& elem, link p);` is not legal C++ and has nothing to do with public/private.  Please read [ask] with a [mcve].  When you get errors include them in the question.

Comment: @RichardCritten I don't get it, I read how to ask and all of this and I don't know what is wrong with my question actually.

Comment: about this->insertafter() is just an example, I want to know how to call a private function within a private function

Comment: "*I want to know how to call a private function within a private function*" - if they are in the same class, then you simply call it normally, eg: `void insertbefore(const ListElemType& elem, link p) { insertafter(elem, p); }`, otherwise you can't call it at all. But like Richard said, you have a syntax error, not an access error.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah it was my mistake I did not notice what I did wrong in my code I was in a hurry ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whenever I try to use the "link" as a parameter in the above functions it's an error.

As it should be.  You can't use a private type as a parameter/return value in a public  method.  Callers of the method that are outside of the class would not have access to the type, and thus could not call the method.

> if I declared the 2 public functions as private, I can't call one in another.

Yes, you can.

> Why so ? even if:
>
> `this->insertafter(const ListElemType& elem, link p);`
>
> It gives me syntax error.

Because it is a syntax error.  The correct syntax would look more like this instead:

```cpp
void inord_list::insertbefore(const ListElemType& elem, link p) {
    this->insertafter(elem, p);
}
```

You can drop the `this->`, though:

```cpp
void inord_list::insertbefore(const ListElemType& elem, link p) {
    insertafter(elem, p);
}
```

Comment: Actually, my bad about the 2nd question, it was my mistake I wrote:
insertafter(const ListElemType e, link p); this was my mistake here sorry I know I sounded stupid :D 
But about the first question, what should I do if I wanted to use *link* variable type ?

Comment: If `link` is `private`, it simply **cannot** be used in code *outside* of the `inord_list` class.  It can only be used inside of `inord_list`'s methods.

Comment: Yeah I know, the insertbefore and insertafter both uses link as parameter, but every time I use it it gave me error unless I made them private, so I was wondering with this way I cannot use link as parameter ??

Comment: I already addressed that in my answer: "*You can't use a private type as a parameter/return value in a public method.*" You may be calling them privately, but you declared them `public`, so `link` would have to be `public` too.